# python / pylint: Type "property" cannot be assigned to type problem

Tags: pylint

I got a problem with trying to annotate some of my code and i can't really wrap my head around it. I simply dont know if its a pylint Problem or I am just to stupid to figured it out.

so I got a class that inherits from type and has a property like so:

```py
class MyType(type):

    @property
    def keys(cls) -> list[str]:
        """
        Property to return a list of Keys
        """
        result: list[str] = [key for key, val in vars(cls).items() if not callable(val)
                and not key.startswith('__')
                or not type(val).__name__ != 'method']
        return result
```

so  I thought i do a Protocol class that Supports this property and i can use this protocol tho annotated stuff in my code.

```py
class IsMyType(Protocol):
    "Protocol to implement an interface for key property"
    @property
    def keys(cls) -> list[str]: ...
```

so now when i try to use it

```py
foo: IsMyType = MyType(bar)
```

I get pylint complaining that

```
Expression of type "Type[__class_MyType]" cannot be assigned to declared type "IsMyType"
  "keys" is an incompatible type
    "property" is incompatible with "list[str]"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

I am close to just do an return of Any in the protocol which is just messed up or simply try to use some

```py
#pylint: disabel=
```

on this. Last resort is simply skipping the whole typing thing for this alltogether.

So if anyone out there has a solution to a situation like that it would be much appreciated.

cheers

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not a full answer. I'll link to some resources below.

1. first problem is that your error isn't from `pylint`, it's from `Pylance`, a Python extension (part of the VSCode extension pack for python) which includes the [pyright type checker](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/). It could be helpful to search for issues on their github page.
2. In fact, if you remove the `(type)` from your `MyType` class definition, you'll see that your code snippet passes type checks. I have no idea if this works for your codebase, but it seems properties changes somehow in the context of metaclasses?

some links

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/5749775
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76071833/5749775
- https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3869