# How to provide type hint for a function that returns an Protocol subclass in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance, subtype, structural-typing

If a function returns a subclass of a `Protocol`, what is the recommended type-hint for the return type of that function?

The following is a simplified piece of code for representation

```
from typing import Protocol, Type
from abc import abstractmethod

class Template(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def display(self) -> None:
        ...
        
class Concrete1(Template):
    def __init__(self, grade: int) -> None:
        self._grade = grade
        
    def display(self) -> None:
        print(f"Displaying {self._grade}")
        
class Concrete2(Template):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name
        
    def display(self) -> None:
        print(f"Printing {self._name}")
        
        
def give_class(type: int) -> Type[Template]:
    if type == 1:
        return Concrete1
    else:
        return Concrete2
    
    
concrete_class =  give_class(1)
concrete_class(5)
```

In the line `concrete_class(5)`, Pylance informs `Expected no arguments to "Template" constructor`.

Comment: Why do you need the same constructor for two subclasses?

Comment: Edited the question so that different subclasses expect different arguments in the constructor

Comment: Does adding an abstract `__init__` to `Template` work? (I haven't tried it myself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Protocols are *not* ABCs

Let me start of by emphasizing that protocols were introduced specifically so you **do not** have to define a nominal subclass to create a subtype relation. That is why it is called **structural** subtyping. To quote [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#rationale-and-goals), the goal was

> allowing users to write [...] code without explicit base classes in the class definition.

While you *can* subclass a protocol explicitly when defining a concrete class, that is not what they were designed for.

**Protocols are not abstract base classes.** By using your protocol like an ABC, you are basically discarding everything that makes a protocol useful in the first place.

---

### Your error and possible solutions

As to why you are getting that error, that is easily explained. Your `Template` protocol does not define its own `__init__` method. When a variable is declared to be of type `type[Template]` (i.e. a class implementing the `Template` protocol) and you want to instantiate it, the type checker will see that `Template` does not define an `__init__` and fall back to the `object.__init__`, which takes **no arguments**. Thus, providing an argument to the constructor is correctly marked as an error.

Since you want to use your protocol not only to annotate *pure instances* that follow it, but also **classes** that you want to instantiate (i.e. `type[Template]`), you need to think about the `__init__` method. If you want to express that for a class to implement your `Template` protocol it can have *any* constructor whatsoever, you should include such a permissive `__init__` signature in the protocol, for example:

```py
class Template(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
```

If you want to be more specific/restrictive, that is possible of course. You could for example declare that `Template`-compliant classes **must** take exactly one argument in their `__init__`, but it can be of any type:

```py
class Template(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, _arg: Any) -> None: ...
```

Both of these solutions would work in your example. The latter however would restrict you from passing a keyword-argument to the constructor with any name other than `_arg` obviously.

---

### Proper structural subtyping

To conclude, I would suggest you *actually* utilize the power of protocols properly to allow for structural subtyping and get rid of the explicit subclassing and `abstractmethod` decorators. If all you care about is a fairly general constructor and your `display` method, you can achieve that like this:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol


class Template(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, _arg: Any) -> None: ...

    def display(self) -> None: ...


class Concrete1:
    def __init__(self, grade: int) -> None:
        self._grade = grade

    def display(self) -> None:
        print(f"Displaying {self._grade}")


class Concrete2:
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name

    def display(self) -> None:
        print(f"Printing {self._name}")


def give_class(type_: int) -> type[Template]:
    if type_ == 1:
        return Concrete1
    else:
        return Concrete2


concrete_class = give_class(1)
concrete_class(5)
```

This passes `mypy --strict` without errors (and should satisfy Pyright too). As you can see, both `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` are accepted as return values for `give_class` because they both follow the `Template` protocol.

---

### Proper use of ABCs

There are of course still valid applications for abstract base classes. For example, if you wanted to define an actual implementation of a method in your base class that itself calls an abstract method, subclassing that *explicitly* (nominal subtyping) can make perfect sense.

Example:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any


class Template(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, _arg: Any) -> None: ...

    @abstractmethod
    def display(self) -> None: ...

    def call_display(self) -> None:
        self.display()


class Concrete1(Template):
    def __init__(self, grade: int) -> None:
        self._grade = grade

    def display(self) -> None:
        print(f"Displaying {self._grade}")


class Concrete2(Template):
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self._name = name

    def display(self) -> None:
        print(f"Printing {self._name}")


def give_class(type_: int) -> type[Template]:
    if type_ == 1:
        return Concrete1
    else:
        return Concrete2


concrete_class = give_class(1)
obj = concrete_class(5)
obj.call_display()  # Displaying 5
```

But that is a totally different use case. Here we have the benefit that `Concrete1` and `Concrete2` are nominal subclasses of `Template`, thus inherit `call_display` from it. Since they are nominal subclasses *anyway*, there is no need for `Template` to be a protocol.

And all this is not to say that it is *impossible* to find applications, where it is useful for something to be both a protocol *and* an abstract base class. But such a use case should be properly justified and from the context of your question I really do not see any justification for it.

Comment: What a great answer and discussion of typing and sub-classing as they relate. One minor detail is that I've not seen `__init__` explicitly mentioned as something that can be part of a protocol definition on the protocols' PEP, and I just wonder if it's fully supported or something to stay away from.

Comment: @matanster Since PEP 544 does not mention it, it is reasonable to conclude that no special treatment is intended for `__init__`. However, in practice it seems it _does_ get special treatment. E.g. mypy currently does not enforce `__init__` types at all. See [this example](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=d4919af1ec210f5881fb162420341d09) and [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3823). An interesting argument is made [here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12970#issuecomment-1153289269). Still, IMO mypy _should_ enforce `__init__` types.